# Ecto Repo loggers config ignored

Tags: elixir, ecto

I tried to set ecto log level to :info and added these lines in my Repo configuration according to [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html):

```
config :app, App.Repo,
  loggers: [
    {Ecto.LogEntry, :log, [:info]}
  ]
```

However what i see in logs is:

```
[debug] QUERY OK db=5.1ms
INSERT INTO ...
```

It's clear that it had no effect.

I also tried adding a custom module:

> ecto_inspector.ex:
>
> ```
> defmodule App.EctoInspector do
>   def log(log) do
>     IO.inspect(log)
>     log
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> config.exs:
>
> ```
> loggers: [
>   {App.EctoInspector, :log, []}
> ]
> ```

Has something changed about the way logging is configured but not updated in docs?

I use Ecto v2.2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [the documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html):

> This option is **processed at compile-time** and may also be given as an option to use `Ecto.Repo`.

Emphasis is mine. Changing your `config.exs` file *won’t* trigger `Ecto` re-build. One might achieve the desired behaviour either by passing this option to `use App.Repo`:

```
use App.Repo, loggers: [{Ecto.LogEntry, :log, [:info]}]
```

or by forcing `Ecto` rebuild with `mix do: clean, deps.compile` (or `mix deps.compile --force ecto` to recompile `Ecto` only, credits to Sascha Wolf.)

Comment: yup this worked. I didn't even think of recompiling dependencies

Comment: You probably might want to read more about compilation phase vs. runtime. All macros are _expanded_ (e.g. translated to AST) in _compile time_, and `Ecto` config surely uses macros to read a log config _to eliminate the unneeded AST completely_. There is no single `if` left in runtime and the code for debug _is not presented in your beam anymore_.

Comment: You can also recompile `ecto` only by using `mix deps.compile --force ecto`